# ASP.NET Core MVC : passing one parameter (from ViewModel) from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm struggling with one case in my application I've main view when I display for admin user list of parameter.

Of course in my view I use data like a model (two string properties, name and value) and with display everything is ok, but when I click Edit (action link) and I want to pass just name of parameter to my edit method in controller (`HttpGet`) but I wanted pass string value not int but all the time I get null value in my method.

Can anyone tell me is if it is possible to pass a string parameter from my model?

My code looks something like this:

Viewmodel which I use

```
@model IEnumerable<ParametersDto>
```

My action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Parameters", new { id=item.Name })</td>
```

Code:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit(string name)        
{
    // ...
}
```

In my method I tried string and my view model (object) like a type but always I have null value.

Comment: You pass the parameter as `id` but try to read it as `name`. Sounds like it's not gonna work.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that the name of parameter pasing between view and controller has meaning. I thougththat more important is type than name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your action method's signature from

```
public IActionResult Edit(string name)
```

to

```
public IActionResult Edit(string id)
```

That should allow the built in binder to hydrate the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ActionLink` hasn't correct; you should fix it like this:

define ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink( linkText,  actionName, controllerName,    routeValues,htmlAttributes)
```

this is correct code

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Edit",           // linkText
    "Edit",           // actionName
    "orders",         // controllerName
    new {             // routeValues
        Name ="sds",
        Value ="sds",
    },
    null              // htmlAttributes
)
```

This is Action Code in Controller

```
public IActionResult Edit(string Name,string Value)
```

[Examples](http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/-Net-MVC-Html-ActionLink-tutorial-with-examples)

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?